# How to retrieve the rows from starting and ending index in firebase database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying pagination feature in my project, I am using react with firebase.

My problem statement: if I have around 50 records in my database, what is the query if we want to select records 3 - 8?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use specific fields in front-end side then use slice and i think you can return your all list from backend and just slice from ui side.

```js
let arr = [
{id:1,name:'One'},
{id:2,name:'Two'},
{id:3,name:'Three'},
{id:4,name:'Four'},
{id:5,name:'Five'},
{id:6,name:'Six'},
{id:7,name:'Seven'},
{id:8,name:'Eight'},
{id:9,name:'Nine'},
{id:10,name:'Ten'}
]
let selected = arr.slice(2,8);
console.log(selected)
```

Comment: I need a firebase query for that

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't have numeric index pagination.  The API allows you to start at the beginning and page through the query results using `startAt()`, `limitToFirst()`, and other related methods, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data).

If you absolutely must use indexes, you will have to read the entire set of results, populate an array, and pick out the desired results from that array using the indexes you want on the page.